# Multiline TextView Edge Clipped But Not During SharedElementTransition

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, textview, shared-element-transition

I have an issue where my `TextView` has characters clipped on its right side only for certain pieces of text. To specify: I don't have a custom font or italic text; it's standard text. Here's an image, there should be an "i" where I have the circle, it's "nitrosoethane" not "ntrosoethane":

[image]

I have found multiple workarounds to fix the clipping, such as setting a text shadow or sub-classing `TextView`. They work, but they don't fix one particular issue. I have a `SharedElementTransition` with this `TextView`, and only when returning to the calling `Activity`, as part of the `SharedElementReturnTransition` animation, the `TextView` decides to wrap on a different character. Interestingly, this wrap is in the correct place to avoid any clipped text. Unfortunately, it ruins the animation effect, because the text jumps to its bugged-out position at the end. Here's a video, as you can see, the text above the line reads "nitrosoethane" for a split second before it switches to "trosoethane":

[image]

I have done a lot of investigation, but I'm really scratching my head on this one. I can neither fix the `TextView` so it wraps on the correct character or make the `TextView` in the animation portray the bug for animation continuity. I've measured the `TextView` before, during, and after the animation, and it's always the same width with the same text and the same font and the same size — same everything (except `measuredWidth` is larger on the `SharedElementEnterTransition`, but that shouldn't effect this, and regular `width` is the same anyway). I don't see why the word wrapping would change only on the return transition. Please help.

Here's the `XML` for the calling `Activity`'s `TextView`:

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    android:id="@+id/name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textColor="@color/text_primary"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/image"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@+id/card"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@+id/formula"
    tools:text="Magnesium Chloride" />
```

And here's the opening `Activity`:

```
<com.google.android.material.textview.MaterialTextView
    android:id="@+id/anim_name"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginStart="32dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:elevation="4dp"
    android:ellipsize="end"
    android:textColor="@color/text_primary"
    android:textSize="18sp"
    android:transitionName="@string/history_anim_name_tran"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toStartOf="@+id/dummy_thumb"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="@id/background"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="@+id/name"
    tools:text="Magnesium Chloride" />
```

This issue doesn't happen for most text, just text like the one I've shown. Also, if you're wondering, I set the `transitionName` programmatically for the first `TextView`. In addition, these two `TextViews` are in `RecyclerViews`.

Comment: A strange problem. The image may simply be overlaying that last character. Check to see if the elevation of the text is greater than the image and, if the elevations are the same, define the _TextView_ after the image so it is rendered later and on top of the image if there is an overlap. This is not necessarily a solution, but it may give some more hints about what is going on. Also, a simple demo of the problem would be helpful if you can arrange that.

Comment: Thanks for your response. The TextView and ImageView are the same elevation and the TextView is defined lower in XML.

Comment: Have you addressed the caveats in [this documentation](https://developer.android.com/guide/fragments/animate#recyclerview) regarding transitions within _RecyclerView_?

Comment: Yes, I made sure the transitions are postponed until images are loaded and that different ItemViews don't contain views with the same transitionName.

Comment: add a border to image and text box and you will know what is happening more precisely. It could even be padding playing up here.

Comment: I've used the Show Layout Bounds tool to see what was going on. The TextView and ImageView don't overlap and the TextView seems to stay the same size throughout the animation.

Comment: I am wondering if this is an issue with _TextView_ or _MaterialTextVIew_. I am also wondering if this is an off-by-one error and you are hitting some boundary condition. It may be of some help to set a pre-draw listener and record the width of the view vs. the width of the first line of the _StaticLayout_.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe I found the issue. It has to do with my `TextView`'s width being dependent on the `ImageView`'s width (which is not know on the first layout pass). For some reason, the `TextView` correctly changes its bounds after the `ImageView` width is updated when the image loads, but the `TextView` still sometimes incorrectly draws some text outside its bounds (which is usually clipped, but can be seen in my question due to a workaround). Calling `invalidate()` or `requestLayout()` doesn't do anything to fix it. But I found a workaround:

If I set the `TextView` to fixed width, the text fits correctly. So as a workaround, I allow the `ConstraintLayout` to layout the `TextView` first, then I manually set the `TextView` width to itself.

```
// Set "match constraints" to determine width
textView.layoutParams.width = 0

textView.text = "Some text"

// Make the width a fixed number after OnLayout()
textView.doOnLayout {
    textView.layoutParams.width = textView.width
}
```

This seems like a bug in `ConstraintLayout`, `TextView`, or their interaction. This fix works in most all cases, except mine, because the card itself is an `itemView` in my `RecyclerView`. I'm not sure why, but the solution doesn't work in my `onBindViewHolder()`. Instead, I simply set the `ImageView` to a fixed width and call it a day.